# pgpool-ii in master/slave mode: How can I most easily trigger a failover?

Tags: postgresql, failover, postgresql-9.4, pgpool

So I am testing some toy postgresql infrastructure with some local virtual machines to determine how pgpool behaves on failover. I've configured a rudimentary setup where I have two database machines (192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3) and a pgpool machine (192.168.0.4). 192.168.0.3 has been setup as a slave to 192.168.0.2 using streaming replication. pgpool-ii has been configured using the following:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
backend_hostname0 = '192.168.0.2'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/'
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
backend_hostname1 = '192.168.0.3'
backend_port1 = 5432
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/'
backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
enable_pool_hba = on
replication_mode = false
master_slave_mode = on
master_slave_sub_mode = 'stream'
fail_over_on_backend_error = true
failover_command = '/root/pgpool_failover_stream.sh %d %H /tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'
load_balance_mode = false
```

I've confirmed this all works. That is, the replication is working when I change the master database, and I can connect to the master, slave, and pgpool-ii with a sample application and get results I expect.

Now, I've started a long running application connecting to pgpool, then attempted to cause failover by SSHing into the master database server and forcibly ending the postgres task (`service postgresql stop` as root). My application keeps executing queries correctly, but no failover occurs (the script has not been run by). I've even tested connecting directly to the master database, and when I stop the postgres service, I do end up crashing the application.

Am I doing something wrong? Have I not configured my pgpool correctly? Or is there a better way to trigger failover?

EDIT: As requested, here is the portion of the log where the first error occurs:

```
...
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1232: DEBUG:  initializing backend status
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1231: DEBUG:  initializing backend status
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1230: DEBUG:  initializing backend status
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1209: ERROR:  failed to authenticate
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1209: DETAIL:  invalid authentication message response type, Expecting 'R' and received 'E'
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1209: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 1
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1209: ERROR:  failed to authenticate
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1209: DETAIL:  invalid authentication message response type, Expecting 'R' and received 'E'
2016-03-15 18:47:15: pid 1209: DEBUG:  find_primary_node: no primary node found
...
```

Strangely, I can still connect to the pgpool and perform queries, so clearly I don't understand something there.

Edit 2: These are the errors I get after `service postgresql shutdown` on the master. I show everything up to start of shutdown of pgpool.

```
...
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  session context: clearing doing extended query messaging. DONE
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  session context: setting doing extended query messaging. DONE
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  session context: setting query in progress. DONE
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  reading backend data packet kind
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DETAIL:  backend:0 of 2 kind = 'E'
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  processing backend response
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DETAIL:  received kind 'E'(45) from backend
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: ERROR:  unable to forward message to frontend
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DETAIL:  FATAL error occured on backend
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  session context: setting query in progress. DONE
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  decide where to send the queries
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DETAIL:  destination = 3 for query= "DISCARD ALL"
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DEBUG:  waiting for query response
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DETAIL:  waiting for backend:0 to complete the query
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: FATAL:  unable to read data from DB node 0
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1012: DETAIL:  EOF encountered with backend
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 998: DEBUG:  reaper handler
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 998: LOG:  child process with pid: 1012 exits with status 256
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 998: LOG:  fork a new child process with pid: 1033
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 998: DEBUG:  reaper handler: exiting normally
2016-03-16 17:24:57: pid 1033: DEBUG:  initializing backend status
2016-03-16 17:25:02: pid 1031: DEBUG:  PCP child receives shutdown request signal 2
2016-03-16 17:25:02: pid 1029: LOG:  child process received shutdown request signal 2
...
```

Note that my sample application did in fact die when the master was shutdown.

EDIT 3: Errors I am getting in new log, after properly setting `sr_check_period`, `sr_check_user`, `sr_check_password`, all previous errors are now gone:

```
2016-03-31 17:45:00: pid 18363: DEBUG:  detect error: kind: 1
2016-03-31 17:45:00: pid 18363: DEBUG:  reading backend data packet kind
2016-03-31 17:45:00: pid 18363: DETAIL:  backend:0 of 2 kind = '1'
...
2016-03-31 17:45:00: pid 18363: DEBUG:  detect error: kind: S
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for the failover script not getting executed. The primary step would be to enable the log_destination property to syslog and enable the debug mode (debug_level =1) .

I have witnessed scenarios where the failover script is unable to get the parameters for %d, %H (the special characters) due to which the script would be unable to ssh to the slave and touch the trigger file.

I can give more details if you post the log file for the same.

Based on the new logs : 
I can see an ERROR:  failed to authenticate . 
Can you check the following parameters of pgpool if they have been configured correctly

health_check_user
health_check_password
recovery_user
recovery_password
wd_lifecheck_user
wd_lifecheck_password
sr_check_user
sr_check_password

I hope you have followed the step of altering the postgres user password

```
alter user postgres password 'yourpassword'
```

and ensure you give the same password in all cases.

From the logs , it looks like an authentication issue. Can you tell me the version of pgpool you are using.

These are the configurations that we are using for a setup with 3 machines (1 master, 1 slave and 1 machine for pgpool)
I have modified to suit your ip address

```
 listen_addresses = '*'
  port = 5433
  socket_dir = '/var/run/postgresql'
  pcp_port = 9898
  pcp_socket_dir = '/var/run/postgresql'

  backend_hostname0 = '192.168.0.2'
  backend_port0 = 5432
  backend_weight0 = 1
  backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main'
  backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'

  backend_hostname1 = '192.168.0.3'
  backend_port1 = 5432
  backend_weight1 = 1
  backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main'
  backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'

  enable_pool_hba = on
  pool_passwd = ''
  authentication_timeout = 60
  ssl = off
  num_init_children = 4
  max_pool = 2
  child_life_time = 300 
  child_max_connections = 0
  connection_life_time = 0
  client_idle_limit = 0
  log_destination = 'stderr,syslog'
  print_timestamp = on
  log_connections = on
  log_hostname = on
  log_statement = on
  log_per_node_statement = on
  log_standby_delay = 'none'
  syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
  syslog_ident = 'pgpool'
  debug_level = 1
  pid_file_name = '/var/run/postgresql/pgpool.pid'
  logdir = '/var/log/postgresql'
  connection_cache = on
  reset_query_list = 'ABORT; DISCARD ALL'

  replication_mode = off
  replicate_select = off
  insert_lock = on
  lobj_lock_table = ''
  replication_stop_on_mismatch = off
  failover_if_affected_tuples_mismatch = off

  load_balance_mode = off
  ignore_leading_white_space = on
  white_function_list = ''
  black_function_list = 'nextval,setval'

  master_slave_mode = on
  master_slave_sub_mode = 'stream'
  sr_check_period = 10
  sr_check_user = 'postgres'
  sr_check_password = 'postgres123'
  delay_threshold = 0
  follow_master_command = ''
  parallel_mode = off
  pgpool2_hostname = 'pgmaster'

  system_db_hostname  = 'localhost'
  system_db_port = 5432
  system_db_dbname = 'pgpool'
  system_db_schema = 'pgpool_catalog'
  system_db_user = 'pgpool'
  system_db_password = ''

  health_check_period = 5
  health_check_timeout = 20
  health_check_user = 'postgres'
  health_check_password = 'postgres123'
  health_check_max_retries = 2
  health_check_retry_delay = 1

  failover_command = '/usr/sbin/failover_modified.sh %d "%H" %P /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/pgsql.trigger.5432'
  failback_command = ''
  fail_over_on_backend_error = on
  search_primary_node_timeout = 10

  recovery_user = 'postgres'
  recovery_password = 'postgres123'
  recovery_1st_stage_command = ''
  recovery_2nd_stage_command = ''
  recovery_timeout = 90
  client_idle_limit_in_recovery = 0

  use_watchdog = off
  trusted_servers = ''
  ping_path = '/bin'
  wd_hostname = ''
  wd_port = 9000
  wd_authkey = ''
  delegate_IP = ''
  ifconfig_path = '/sbin'
  if_up_cmd = 'ifconfig eth0:0 inet $_IP_$ netmask 255.255.255.0'
  if_down_cmd = 'ifconfig eth0:0 down'
  arping_path = '/usr/sbin'  
  arping_cmd = 'arping -U $_IP_$ -w 1'

  clear_memqcache_on_escalation = on
  wd_escalation_command = ''

  wd_lifecheck_method = 'heartbeat'
  wd_interval = 10
  wd_heartbeat_port = 9694
  wd_heartbeat_keepalive = 2
  wd_heartbeat_deadtime = 30
  heartbeat_destination0 = '192.168.0.2'
  heartbeat_destination_port0 = 9694
  heartbeat_device0 = ''

  heartbeat_destination1 = '192.168.0.3'
  wd_life_point = 3
  wd_lifecheck_query = 'SELECT 1'
  wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'postgres'
  wd_lifecheck_user = 'postgres'
  wd_lifecheck_password = 'postgres123'

  relcache_expire = 0
  relcache_size = 256
  check_temp_table = on

  memory_cache_enabled = off
  memqcache_method = 'shmem'
  memqcache_memcached_host = 'localhost'
  memqcache_memcached_port = 11211
  memqcache_total_size = 67108864
  memqcache_max_num_cache = 1000000
  memqcache_expire = 0
  memqcache_auto_cache_invalidation = on
  memqcache_maxcache = 409600
  memqcache_cache_block_size = 1048576
  memqcache_oiddir = '/var/log/pgpool/oiddir'
  white_memqcache_table_list = ''
  black_memqcache_table_list = ''
```

Also, i hope you have modified the pool_hba.conf to enable access to master and slave

Comment: Hi Raveesh, thank you for your reply! I've enabled logging and even just on startup I've noticed some errors seem likely to be relevant. I've edited my question to include the necessary information.

Comment: Can you give the logs that occur once you have shut down the master. I think these logs do not point to the real problem of "why the failover does not execute the script"

Comment: Updated again with requested log info.

Comment: Sorry that it has been a while. Setting `sr_check_period` and friends removed previous errors I was getting. Now I have new errors!

EDIT: That didn't work, I've now updated the question.